# If exact word sequence matches from one dataframe in other dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, where df1 has column key1 and df2 has column key2. Here column key1 contains values as "arsenal tickets", "baby spoon" AND column key2 contains values as "baby s", "tickets"

I used below solution which does not gives expected result:

```
var filterdf = df1.join(df2, $"key1".contains($"key2"))

filterdf.show
```

result:

```
+--------------------+----------------+
|                key1|key2            |
+--------------------+----------------+
|          baby spoon|          baby s|
|     arsenal tickets|         tickets|
+--------------------+----------------+
```

The expected result should be as below, it should not include 'baby spoon'. It should match the exact words sequence with no extra literals.

```
+--------------------+----------------+
|                key1|key2            |
+--------------------+----------------+
|     arsenal tickets|         tickets|
+--------------------+----------------+
```

What do I do to get the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can include Trim() function to remove whitespaces when you are passing df2 i.e

```
var filterdf = df1.join(df2, $"key1".contains(trim($"key2")))

filterdf.show
```